# What are behaviours in Polymer JS?

Tags: polymer-1.0

What are behaviours in Polymer JS? What do they actually hold? For a long time, I have been unable to understand what they are used for.

Comment: @Conor Pender: thanks for your correction after one year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First definition as per Polymer JS doc:**

Polymer supports extending custom element prototypes with shared code modules called behaviors.

A behavior is an object that looks similar to a typical Polymer prototype. A behavior can define lifecycle callbacks , declared properties, default attributes, observers, and listeners.

**In simple words:**

Behaviours means that properties, listeners, methods, variables required for particular elements are coming ready to use. suppose Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior then required properties, listeners, methods, variables of overlay are predefined in that behaviour so we can directly use them.